# C# How to remove specific nodes from list

Tags: c#, list, traversal, removechild

I have the following class

```
public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public bool IsLastItem { get; set; }
}
```

Let say I have the following model and I want to remove items which `IsLastItem = false` and don't have child. In this scenario item4 and item7 should remove from list.

[image: Model]

I get the list of my model from database and I simulated it in the code block like this

```
var items = new List<Item>
{
    new Item
    {
        Id = 1,
        ParentId = 0,
        Content = "item1",
        IsLastItem = false
    },
    new Item
    {
        Id = 2,
        ParentId = 1,
        Content = "item2",
        IsLastItem = false
    },
    new Item
    {
        Id = 3,
        ParentId = 1,
        Content = "item3",
        IsLastItem = true
    },
    new Item
    {
        Id = 4,
        ParentId = 1,
        Content = "item4",
        IsLastItem = false
    },
    new Item
    {
        Id = 5,
        ParentId = 2,
        Content = "item5",
        IsLastItem = false
    },
    new Item
    {
        Id = 6,
        ParentId = 5,
        Content = "item6",
        IsLastItem = false
    },
    new Item
    {
        Id = 7,
        ParentId = 5,
        Content = "item7",
        IsLastItem = false
    },
    new Item
    {
        Id = 8,
        ParentId = 6,
        Content = "item8",
        IsLastItem = true
    },
    new Item
    {
        Id = 9,
        ParentId = 8,
        Content = "item9",
        IsLastItem = true
    }
};
```

Comment: do you want to remove them by id or all nodes without a child? If you want to remove all nodes without a child, why don't you remove node 9 too?

Comment: `var enumerable = items.Where(s => !s.IsLastItem && items.All(t => t.ParentId != s.Id)).ToList();` ???

Comment: @MichałZych: users can create a model which item4 is not last item but I have to clear these nodes.

Comment: @dr_debug: because it has 'IsLastItem = true' property.

Comment: @Aybe: sorry. it doesn't work for my case. I need to remove just item4 and item7 because these items don't have child and have IsLastItem property false.

Comment: A [LinkedList<T>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7(v=vs.110).aspx) might yield you better performance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A flat list like this is not optimal for these kinds of operations - it might be nice if you could get the list back in some kind of tree structure (maybe return it from SQL using `FOR XML` or JSON if you're on 2016) to begin with, where you'd have an easier time traversing the tree.

Also note that, as is, your sample data isn't setting IsLastItem...

As is, you have to iterate at least twice, something like this:

```
items.RemoveAll(x => x.IsLastItem == false && 
    items.Any(y => y.ParentId == x.Id) == false);
```

You're saying to remove all the items where `IsLastItem` is false and where there's not at least one item whose parent id is that item's id.

Comment: He's answer removed item9 because in your simulated code block you set IsLastItem to false for item9. He's solution works just fine.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to set `IsLastItem` in your mocked up data, FYI.  You should be able to accomplish this with `RemoveAll`.

```
public static void Main()
{
    var items = init();
    items.RemoveAll(x => !items.Any(y => y.ParentId == x.Id) == true && x.IsLastItem == false);         

}

public static List<Item> init()
{           
    return new List<Item>
    {
        new Item
        {
            Id = 1,
            ParentId = 0,
            Content = "item1"
        },
            new Item
        {
            Id = 2,
            ParentId = 1,
            Content = "item2"
        },
            new Item
        {
            Id = 3,
            ParentId = 1,
            Content = "item3",
            IsLastItem = true
        },
            new Item
        {
            Id = 4,
            ParentId = 1,
            Content = "item4"
        },
            new Item
        {
            Id = 5,
            ParentId = 2,
            Content = "item5"
        },
            new Item
        {
            Id = 6,
            ParentId = 5,
            Content = "item6"
        },
            new Item
        {
            Id = 7,
            ParentId = 5,
            Content = "item7"
        },
            new Item
        {
            Id = 8,
            ParentId = 6,
            Content = "item8"
        },
            new Item
        {
            Id = 9,
            ParentId = 8,
            Content = "item9",
            IsLastItem = true
        }
    };      
}
```

Comment: sorry I forgot to add it to model. I just edit the question :)

Answer (score 1):

Find the ParentIds.  Compare each item to the list of ParentId collection and check IsLastitem.

```
var parents = items.Select(x => x.ParentId);
items.RemoveAll(x => !parents.Contains(x.Id) && !x.IsLastItem);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use a tree-like structure, and make IsLastItem a property that is calculated:

```
public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public List<Item> SubItems { get; set; }
    public bool IsLastItem { get { return SubItems.Count == 0; } }
}
```

Since the items stored in the database will have a flat structure, you'll have to write a function to create the tree from the database (and write the tree out to the database if necessary), but once that's done, the tree will be easier to manipulate.

You'd then write a recursive function to remove all last nodes, something like this:

```
List<Item> RemoveNodes(List<Item> tree)
{
    var ret = tree.Where(item => !item.IsLastItem);
    foreach (Item item in ret)
    {
        item.SubItems = RemoveNodes(item.SubItems);
    }
    return ret;
}
```

That may not be exactly the best way to do it but you get the idea.